# Problema en el uso de linear-gradient en css

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente codigo ...

```css
body{
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #051937, #004d7a, #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12);
}

.main-container{
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #09f;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Asyncronous js</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-container">
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

La idea es que el color de fondo de la pagina tenga el degradado, por que se divide por la mitad la pagina?

Comment: No entiendo cómo la respuesta a esta pregunta no está aceptada. ¿no te funcionó?

Answer (score 2):

La cuestión es simple, es que la etiqueta `<body>` no ha ocupado toda la pantalla.

Intenta aplicarle el estilo al html junto con `width` y `height` y mira la diferencia:

```css
html {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #051937, #004d7a, #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Realizé el código de muestra para que lo puedas probar aquí mismo...

```css
html {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #051937, #004d7a, #008793, #00bf72, #a8eb12);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin : 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-container{
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #09f;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>Asyncronous js</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-container">
            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comenta si funcionó, Saludos!